# Change menu bar width

Tags: css

I'm trying to center the menu bar and make the menu bar fit the text. 
Here is a website I'm trying to edit:
http://www.graffitisumperk.g6.cz/blog/

I've already figure out that I can center menu items this way:

```
.menu {
    text-align:center
}
.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.menu li li {
    display:block;
    text-align:left
}
```

But I can't seem to fit the menu bar to the width of the menu items.
I've calculated it should be 445px long, but when I change this:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
```

to 445px, the whole page it affected, not just the menu bar.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very very similarly :). One of the effects of `display: inline-block;` is that the element attempts to resize itself to contain its children. You could achieve this with `float` or `position: absolute` as well, but those do not really fit into this layout.

```
.main-nav { text-align: center; }
.menu { display: inline-block; }
```

I guessed you might want to center the menu, so I added the `text-align` too.

**Tip**: If you use the inspector of your browser (all modern browsers have a pretty decent one), you can easily figure out which element you need to change.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply bažmegakapa. I've tried to add your lines to the css, but the page looks the same.
I've replaced this line 
`.main-nav {
 clear:both;
}`
with this
`.main-nav { text-align: center; }`
and added
`.menu { display: inline-block; }`

What em I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlešKroutil It's quite hard to tell without seeing it in action. Can you post some demo?

Comment: I added `.main-nav { text-align: center; }
.menu { display: inline-block; }` to the Custom CSS Style field in the Wordpress Theme settings. You can see it in action right here [link](http://www.graffitisumperk.g6.cz/)

Comment: @AlešKroutil Check in the inspector of your browser. Another rule is overwriting your `.menu` rule, because it is stronger: `.js .main-nav .menu { display: block; }`. Remove this and it is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at your page, it looks like the part you really need to change is the "main-nav" class.

The #container div contains your whole page so you don't want to mess with that one.